# Initiate groovy class with map

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am using the shared libraries feature of jenkins for when running my pipeline scripts and would like to initialise the library with a map of variables.

I simply have a file (called `Pipeline.groovy`) that looks like so

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
package path.of.package; 

def method() {
  # do stuff
}

def method2() {
  # do more stuff
}
```

The library gets initialised like so in my pipeline script

```
def groovyMethod = new Pipeline()
```

and i just access the methods like

```
groovyMethod.method()
```

I would like to be able to pass in a `map` like this

```
def map = [version: "123",
           name: "Name",
           library: 'Library Name'
          ]
```

is this possible with my current setup ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either call a constructor with named params:

```
Pipeline p = new Pipeline( version: "123",
       name: "Name",
       library: 'Library Name' )
```

or pass the map into the constructor:

```
Pipeline p = new Pipeline( map )
```

or make groovy casting:

```
Pipeline p = [ version: "123",
       name: "Name",
       library: 'Library Name' ] as Pipeline
```

The prerequisite for the abovementioned actions is the presence of a default no-arg constructor.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.. so with the second example `pass the map into the constructor`, I can create my map before initializing and then pass it in ?